# why is my function no longer working

Tags: php

Well it was working not too long ago, now it seems not to be working. Can anybody identify the issue. I am not being able to. Here is the code:

```
function updateLogout() {
    session_start();
    $session = "";
    $offline="Offline";
    $sql = "UPDATE `user` SET last_sign_in_stamp = '".time()."', online = '".$offline."', session = '".$session."' WHERE username='" . fixstr($_POST['username']) . "' AND password='" . fixstr($_POST['password']) . "' AND active = 1 ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close();  
}
```

Does anybody konw what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: Does there seem to be an obvious reason why the code above is not updating my table? Is not doing anything...

Comment: You have a `mysql_close`, but not a `mysql_connect` or `mysql_select_db`. Where are they and why are they not in the same function?

Comment: pls change it to `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and tell us the error you are seeing

Comment: To clarify @mithunsatheesh's comment: that whole codeblock is one statement, not either the first or the second part.

Comment: They are located on my logout page before the session_unset();
session_destroy();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your connection in the function.. I suggest learning MySQLi or PDO.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 1):

Shared server perhaps? Did your provider recently upgrade php?
My guess is that mysql_query function (and all other mysql_ functions) is now depriated on that server. can you do a 'SELECT NOW()' query and get an answer?
If not, you can use mysqli or PDO for MySQL.

Comment: Deprecation != discontinuation